# Unable to generate logs,but log file is creating with empty source?

Tags: java, jsp, logging, log4j, properties-file

I'm using index.jsp ,there i'm writing code to generate log files,every thing is working fine but even though exception comes log messages are not generating.Here is my code.

```
<body>
    <%
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("index");
        String prefix = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        String file = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("log4j-init-file");
        System.setProperty("appRootPath", prefix);
        //out.println(file);
        // if the log4j-init-file context parameter is not set, then no point in trying
        if (file != null) {
            PropertyConfigurator.configure(prefix + file);
            out.println("Log4J Logging started: " + prefix + file);
            int i = 10, j = 0;
            try {
                int k = i / j;
                out.println(k);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                logger.error("Exception", ex);
            }               
            // logger.error("This is a warning message" + file);
        } else {
            out.println("Log4J Is not configured for your Application: " + prefix + file);
        }
    %>
</body>
```

and this is my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>log4j-init-file</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>         
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and this is my properties file

```
log4j.logger.Logging=DEBUG, C, fileappender 
log4j.additivity.Logging=true
log4j.appender.C=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.C.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.C.layout.ConversionPattern=[%c] [%d{dd MMM yyyy - hh:mm:ss}] %5p - %m %n
log4j.appender.fileappender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileappender.file=${appRootPath}WEB-INF/logs/Logging.log
log4j.appender.fileappender.MaxFileSize=500KB
log4j.appender.fileappender.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.fileappender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileappender.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

Here i gave pathe MyApp.log that is generating but when exception come log messages has to generate ,it is not generating any log messages,whats wrong in this code.could anybody guide me please.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j pages state you should add log4j-web module to your deployment - https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html
Also this page has some other useful information you may need.